# How to create voting to a multiple choice application using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, voting

I am working on a multiple choice question and answer application using Ruby on Rails and I have the following model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
end  

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :answer
end
```

My problem is a user can choose all the answers.

How can I fix it so that it updates to the new answer?

For example, `a` has 5 votes and `b` 3 votes.

User clicks on `a` and `a` increments to 6 votes, same user comes back and clicks on `b`, `a` decrements back to 5 votes and `b` increments to 4 votes.

My first guess is that I need to add another model for example, `user_choice` with `user_id` and `vote_id` to track the previous answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your answer within the models. Just add a point system to the question model.

Under the question model,

```
def points
  self.answers.count
end
```

Or, if answers have different values attached to them, make points an attribute of the answer instances.

```
def points
  self.answers.pluck(:points).inject(:+)
end
```

This will sum up all the points from an answer belonging to a question, which allows you to order the questions by point count.

However, I am assuming you will need a Choice model for a question, unless that is in fact what the votes are for.

question has_many choices

choices belong_to question, etc.

I'm not sure what you mean when you say:

> How can I fix it so that it updates to the new answer?

## EDIT

Er, okay so you just need exactly what I mentioned earlier. A vote is really just the number of times an answer has been chosen.

If your problem is that users can choose more than 1 answer, it is likely that you should implement view based validations via javascript, or better yet, just disable their ability to select multiple choices, which if you were using a select tag, is actually the default. You must've added

```
multiple: true
```

in the select tag options for the user to select multiple entries.

On the backend, you can do this:

```
class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: [:question_id, :answer_id]
end
```

Comment: I gave an example. Answers will display as links and users can only pick one answer like any multiple choice question

Comment: I am using links not select tags.

Comment: you should be using a form to submit it, with ajax maybe. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: my main problem is how prevent user from choosing all the answers.

Comment: your main problem is you are using a link to do something a form should be doing, link_to is really only suitable if you are doing something like changing a state, or a boolean variable

Comment: I found a gem that does something similar to what I am looking for, the [robut-quiz](https://github.com/burtio/robut-quiz) only it's a sinatra gem. You know how facebook questions worked when user post a question and friends respond by clicking on either yes or no and it returns the number of vote for each. I want something like that only user provide custom options for the questions. I really appreciate your taking time this and I hope you understand what I am trying to achieve. many thanx.